# Azure pipelines strategy: Do I have to create one pipeline for pre-merging pull request code? or reuse

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, devops

I'm working on a solution that has a yaml build pipeline that does the following

```
>restore
>build
>test
>publish test
>publish test coverage
>publish source code
```

And I want to implement a policy in a branch that does the following: whenever a developer creates a pull request to `develop` branch, that action triggers a build to ensure that the code the developer is trying to merge to develop builds and passes all tests

My question is: as a best practice, should I reuse the build pipeline that I already have, or should I create a new pipeline for that specific job?

Comment: Unless you need completely different behavior, use the same pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Rodrigo you can use the same pipeline as long as you don't have some specific requirements. You can make use of conditions or stages in pipeline yaml to make it robust reuse.

for more information

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema